# How to make custom view scrollable along with Expandable List view ...?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have a one custome view and on expandable list view.

list is scrolling fine but when i tried to place both in a scroll view its not working.

I decided to place the custom view in one of the element in the expandable list view.

But, each element in the list has two items Group and Childs.

How to replace both of them with my view at first position...?

[image]

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Why dont you put your custom view as a header view to the listview?

Comment: @David Hi, its working now but how to remove the array mark on head in the list.

Comment: +1 nice explanation with superb image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got a solution for this.

Load your custom view into the ExpandableListView as Group with 0 children.

Then make group indicator invisible.. that's it. :)